# Element created on keydown using JavaScript createElement() method won't work with the jQuery draggable() method

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm working on a drag and drop project where items can be added to a work area and dragged to be positioned. I am trying to use a key code to create multiple of the same kind of element, all of which can be dragged. The jQuery function works as long as the draggable element is created when the page loads, but if it's created using a function, the draggable() method isn't working on it. Is there a way to get the function to recognize the element created with a function?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Draggable Div Test</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <style>
    .test {
      width: 50px;
      height: 50px;
    }
  </style>
  
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="area" style="border: 1px solid black; width: 500px; height: 500px;"> </div>
  
  <script>
    var area = document.getElementById("area");
    function duplicate(e) {
      switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 49:
        var test = document.createElement("div");
        test.classList.add("test");
        test.classList.add("draggable");
        console.log(test.classList)
        test.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        area.appendChild(test);

        break
      }
    }
    document.addEventListener("keydown", duplicate)

    $( function() {
      $( ".test" ).draggable();
    } );
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery draggable has a function called `clone`:

```
 $(function() {
     i = 0

     $("#draggable").draggable({
         helper: 'clone',
         appendTo: "#droppable",
     });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        accept: "#draggable",
    }); 

    i++;

    var $obj = ui.helper.clone().attr( 'data-name', 'newelementdropped' +i).draggable({
   stop : function (event, ui) {
    YOUR CODE
    });
}
```

See this answer: [Jquery draggable(), clone() to append div...Pls Fiddle my jsfiddle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18496844/jquery-draggable-clone-to-append-div-pls-fiddle-my-jsfiddle/18497380)

Answer (score 1):

Just re-initalize the plugin after you insert the element.

Something like:

```
$(".test").draggable("destroy").draggable();
```

Comment: I tried this and had the same result. Is there another way to re-initialize the plugin? Thanks